# Normal to a set of integer vectors

Tags: computational-geometry, linear-diophantine-equations

Given a set of $i$ integer vectors resting in $d$ space (with $i$ < $d$), how do you find a normal to the set of vectors while keeping all of the computations in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Is your $d$ space actually $Z^d$? Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_lattice

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a solution of a system of linear Diophantine equations:
$$AX = 0$$
where $A$ is a matrix of your integer vectors, and $X$ - the normal vector you want to find.

Please look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations) for additional information.

Welcome to the site!